# Error: error:interr Interpolation Error while apply dynamic custom filter in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, treegrid

I am using tree grid (http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html)  and based on column/header type apply the respective filter. I have created custom filter and applied to ng-repeat.

### Error:

```
Can't interpolate: {{row.branch[col.field] | custom : treeGridTest.filterArray[col.field]}}
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=undefinedFilterProvider%20%3C-%20undefinedFilter
```

Suggest me where the thing goes wrong.

### treeGrid.js

```
var app = angular.module('treeGridTest', ['treeGrid']);

app.controller('treeGridController', function($scope) {

    $scope.filterArray = {
         'Sales': 'currency',
         'Profit': 'currency',
         'Area' : 'lowercase'
     };
});

app.filter('custom', ['$filter', function (segmentio) {
    return function (value, type) {
        return segmentio(type)(value);
    }
}]);
```

### tree-grid-directive.js

```
var module = angular.module('treeGrid',[]);
  module.directive('treeGrid', [
    '$timeout', function($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'tree-grid-template.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          treeData: '=',
          colDefs:'=',
          expandOn:'=',
          onSelect: '&',
          initialSelection: '@',
          treeControl: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        /* Some code */
      };
    }
  ]);
```

### tree-grid-template.html

```
<td ng-repeat="col in colDefinitions" >
    {{row.branch[col.field] | custom : treeGridTest.filterArray[col.field]}}
</td>
```